# Signal Switching Advice/Recommendation needed

Tags: relay, noise, switching

I need to design a switching circuits for this:

A tester device is used to test a controller(lets call it controller A). This controller have both input/ouput(analog and digital for each) which is currently tested by the testing machine.

I have to expand functionality of the tester so that controller B can also be tested(not at the same time). Controller B has same number of pin as controller A, but each pin each assigned different channel type(analog in controller A, digital in controller B, vice versa).

So I will have to make separate wiring harness for controller B, and have to switch back and forth every time.

So I decide to use relays to accomplished switching. There are approximately 35 pins with channel type mismatched, I am thinking about using six 6pole-double throw relay which will switched for desired configuration.  I am using this relays http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-potter-brumfield-relays/R10-E1Z6-V430/PB775-ND/813841. My question is given the situation I just described, are there better way(I may have missed) to accomplish this?

Notes:Another issue is pins are group by connector on both DUT and tester side. And signal that needs to be switched are not necessarily in same connector.

Comment: I'd stick with adaptor cables -particularly if there is any chance you may get additional board types to test.

Comment: Could you elaborate adapter cables?

Comment: Adaptor cable = wiring harness.  Make a cable with one end fitting the present connector, and the other fitting Controller B.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9fhp1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Don't bother switching. Wire up your test fixtures permanently to the tester or use plug or PCBs and sockets. Do your criss-cross wiring between the sockets (A, B and C in the sketch). As long as you only have one board in at a time you won't have any problem.